# Double tap ctrl-q to quit applications

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, ux

On MacOS I'm using Karabiner-Elements (https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to set up *cmd-q* so I have to double tap it to quit applications. This prevents quitting applications by mistake when using cmd-w to close windows for example.

So basically I will *press and hold cmd* and then *double tap q*.

Is it possible to set up Ubuntu to do the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Each program, on its own, decides how to let you quit. There's no system-wide "quit" that you could repurpose.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm asking for is a way for ctrl-q to _not register_ until I tapped q _twice_.

Comment: @waltinator this is actually not true. There is a gnome setting called "close window" that I have set to ctrl+q and it works for every app.

Comment: @AlexFullam that is "close window", not "close application".